# Video recording with OpenVidu and electron

Tags: electron, webrtc, openvidu

I have to be able to record an incoming video call into a file. The recording must be done on the desktop application, built with electron. I'm using OpenVidu as a streaming platform. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Vasniktel Technically it could be possible to record the video client side as there are a number of WebRTC examples that record locally on the client, however this is not natvie to openvidu. However recording on electronjs is...

github.com/hokein/electron-screen-recorder

tutorialspoint.com/electron/… You could integrate recording separately along side your openvidu app.

The main difference here is that you want to record an incoming call and while you likely won't be able to just write the incoming webrtc data you should be able to record the area of the app (canvas) where the video player is rendered.  You will be re-encoding the decoded rendered video stream, but it shouldn't be too much of a hit performance wise.

Comment: @Vasniktel Don't forget to accept answers if you feel your question was adequately answered.

Comment: @Vasniktel: Can you please share the solution if possible?